# Construct hadamard matrix of order 12

Tags: coding-theory

How do you construct a hadamard matrix of order 12?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can find the original paper and if you can read french, then Hadamard actually constructed such a matrix of order 12 in his "Résolution d'une question relative aux déterminants" in 1893.

Comment: Here is the document I told you about: http://archive.org/details/s2bulletindessci17fran. What you're looking for is at pages 243 to 246 ;)

Comment: N.J.A. Sloane maintains (in addition to OEIS) [A Library of Hadamard Matrices](http://neilsloane.com/hadamard/).

Answer (score 5):

One possibility of constructing such [Hadamard matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) is to use [Paley construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction).

In this construction we use a finite field with $q$ elements and:

- For $q\equiv3\pmod4$ we get a matrix of order $(q+1)$.
- For $q\equiv1\pmod4$ we get a matrix of order $2(q+1)$.

So for $q=5$ or $q=11$ we get a $12\times12$-matrix.

This construction is described also in the book *van Lint J., Wilson R. A course in combinatorics*, see [Theorem 18.5](http://books.google.com/books?id=5l5ps2JkyT0C&pg=PA203).

Answer (score 3):

- A recursive method to construct Hadamard matrices of order $4.3^n$, $n\geq 1$, with the matrices for even $n$ having the additional property of being regular, was provided in the paper "[A recursive construction for new symmetric designs](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10623-003-6740-0)" by Ionin and Kharaghani.

(A regular Hadamard matrix is one where the row sums and column sums are constant)

Theorem 2.1 in the paper states,

> Let matrices $A_n$ and $B_n$ be defined recursively for $n\geq 1$ by $A_n = B_{n-1} \otimes I$ and $B_n = A_{n-1} \otimes J+B_{n-1} \otimes Q$. Then for each $n\geq0$, $H_n = A_n + B_n$ and $H^{'}_n = A_n - B_n$ are Hadamard matrices and $H_{2n}$ is a regular Hadamard matrix. Furthermore, each row of every matrix $H_n$ can be represented as a $1\times 4$ block-matrix $[H_{n1}H_{n2}H_{n3}H_{n4}]$, where each block is  a $1 \times 3^n$ matrix, which in turn can be represented as a block-matrix $[X_1,X_2, \cdots ,X_{3^{n-1}}]$ with each block being a row of $\pm J$ or a row of $\pm(I+Q).$

with
$Q =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & - & 1 \\
1 & 0 & - \\
- & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$, 
$A_0 =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
- & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$, 
$B_0 =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & - & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & - \\
1 & - & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$

$I$ is the identity matrix of order $4.3^n$ and $J$ is the matrix of all ones of order $4.3^n$

This should give you a family of pairs of Hadamard matrices for each value of n.

- Another way to construct a Hadamard matrix of order 12 could be this:

Find a Generalized Hadamard matrix $GH$ of order 12 over an elementary abelian group of order 4 ($\mathbb{Z_{2}} \times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$). Denote the elements of the group as the set of vectors of dimension 2 over $GF(2)$.
As an example,
$EA_(4)$ = $\{(1,1),(1,-),(-,1),(-,-)\}$, the group operation is the component-wise product of two vectors.

The $GH$ matrix can be "split" to obtain 2 matrices. First, consider the matrix formed by taking the first element of each vector seperately, and another matrix formed by taking the second element of each vector seperately.
For eg.
for $GH(12,EA(4)) = [GH_{ij}]$, $1 \leq i \leq 12, 1 \leq j \leq 12$,
(The notation refers to the Generalized Hadamard matrix of order 12 over an elementary abelian group of order 4);
Form two matrices $H^1$ and $H^2$ of order 12, such that,
if $GH_{ij}$ = $(a,b)$, then $H_{ij}^1 = a$ and $H_{ij}^2 = b$.

Both $H^1$ and $H^2$ are Hadamard matrices.
You can find an example of $GH(12,EA(4))$, due to Jennifer Seberry [here](http://www.uow.edu.au/~jennie/WEBPDF/081_1980_Example_A.pdf).

I'm not sure if this method will yield $k$ Hadamard matrices for every $GH(n,EA(2^k))$, $n$ divisible by $2^k$. I don't have a constructive proof of this yet, but I guess you can try and prove it by assuming that every element of an $EA(2^k)$ corresponds to a column of an Hadamard matrix of order $2^k$ obtained using Sylvester's construction.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short skript using my matrix-calculator-program MatMate: (see matrix-results at bottom of post)

```
n=12
M = einh(n)*sqrt(n)          // define a diagonal matrix containing only sqrt(n)
W = M * gettrans(randomn(n,n),"drei")  // rotate it in some random direction just
                             // to make it non-diagonal

// now find a Hadamard-version from that "random" matrix: 
X = rot ( W, "-varimax")     // do a "varimax"-rotation with minimizing condition
```

The reason why I post here a skript straightaway is, that it is as simple as this to produce any $n=4 \times m$, given that some hypothese can actually be proven: that the "varimax"-rotation can be configured to find the global optimum (and as opposed need not stick in local minima).
Unfortunately it seems, that the numerical process needs a high digits-accuracy depending on *n*; so for *n=20* I needed *80* to *100* digits and I could not yet make the varimax-rotation ***definitely converging*** to the true result for more than *n=28* (The finding of the solution depends on that we have a "nice" random configuration in *W* so far).
But for *n=12* this works in a fraction of a second with double accuracy and always perfectly.

See also my question concerning this at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90558)

---

*A bit background:* The "varimax"-rotation is an iterative process, which for each rotation of pairs of columns optimizes the rotation angle such that the variance in the squared entries of that columns arrives at a maximum. For our case that maximum-criterion is converted into a ***minimum***-criterion instead (such that the variance of the squares in each pairs becomes minimal in each rotation - and in our case of a Hadamard-matrix becomes zero).
This rotation-idea stems from the "factor analysis" in multivariate statistics and more about it can be found for instance in wikipedia.

Unfortunately I didn't find a conclusive and explicite proof for that hypothese so far, although there is some work on it, for instance by J.M.F. ten Berge (Idon't have the exact citation at hand in the moment)

---

$$  \text{ w =} \tiny \left[ \begin{array} {rrrrrrrrrrrr} 
 -0.5032&  0.3615&  0.0332& -1.2641&  1.4063&  0.4272&  0.3647& -1.6180&  1.7986& -0.9712& -0.7984& -0.5388\\
  0.8396&  1.6039& -0.5397&  0.1197&  0.8540&  1.4172& -1.0500& -0.0552& -0.3709& -0.4297&  1.9723& -0.6007\\
  1.9841& -0.3399& -0.9440&  1.1765&  0.1358&  0.3534&  1.7796&  0.0362&  1.4002&  0.5702&  0.1865&  0.2011\\
 -1.5781& -0.7268& -1.6570&  0.5068& -0.6434&  1.7556&  0.1298&  0.9972&  0.4021& -1.1098& -0.2211&  0.1716\\
 -0.0793& -0.9447&  1.5442& -0.9225& -0.3774&  1.8690&  1.1637&  0.0869& -0.4804&  0.9362&  0.4572& -1.2458\\
  0.4887&  0.1290& -0.6250& -1.8390&  0.4173&  0.9115& -0.3324&  0.4091& -0.1530&  1.2227& -0.4574&  2.2274\\
 -0.7221&  0.1901&  0.7917&  0.9587& -1.1709&  0.5620& -1.3225& -0.9337&  1.7662&  1.3659&  0.4962&  0.5981\\
 -0.2871&  1.6300& -0.9170& -0.6776& -2.0357& -0.1423&  1.2733& -1.3285& -0.6295&  0.0588&  0.0966& -0.0303\\
 -0.9945&  1.5586& -0.1792&  1.1322&  1.2046&  0.4103&  0.4685&  0.4422& -0.4850&  1.5998& -1.4418& -0.6000\\
 -0.5021&  1.4566&  1.4777& -0.2281& -0.1317& -0.2928&  1.0954&  1.7771&  1.0272& -0.8284&  0.6311&  0.8887\\
  0.2277& -0.0026&  1.1739&  1.3336&  0.3194&  1.0599&  0.4326& -1.3095& -1.1589& -1.1607& -0.5319&  1.6404\\
 -1.5724& -0.7072& -0.4838&  0.1526&  1.2077& -0.7515&  1.0673& -0.7094& -0.3190&  0.6941&  1.9887&  0.7524
 \end{array}
 \right] $$

$$  \text{ X =} \tiny \left[ \begin{array} {rrrrrrrrrrrr} 
   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00\\
   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00\\
1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00\\
   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00\\
   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00\\
1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00\\
   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00\\
   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00\\
   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00\\
   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00&    1.00\\
1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00\\
   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&   -1.00&    1.00&    1.00
 \end{array} \right]$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll translate what is said in the document I gave you the link for (from Hadamard's work). He explains how to construct a Hadamard matrix of order 12 (although he doesn't call them Hadamard matrices :))

Basically he starts by saying that columns must be groupped 3 by 3 in 4 seperate groups.

Next, he describes the first $3$ lines:

- The first line only has $1$'s.
- The second line has only $1$'s in the first two groups and $(-1)$'s in the last two groups
- The third line has alternating $1$'s and $(-1)$'s

And finally, he describes how the last $9$ lines are arranged:

Each of these lines is constructed in such a way that:

- The first and last groups each have $2$ positive elements and $1$ negative element.
- The second and third groups each have $1$ positive element and $2$ negative elements.

Note that in every line, each group has one element which sign is different from the two other elements in the group.

Also, these lines have to verify the following table:

$$\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\1 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 3 & 2 & 1\end{array}$$

Where:

- Each $i$-th column of the table represents the $i$-th column group of the matrix.
- The numbers indicate the rank of the element which sign is different from the two other elements of the group

**Note:** He also has a similar approach for Hadamard matrices of order $20$ if you're interested ;)